# Creating County level Adjacency Matrix for different states

Tags: r, matrix

I'm attempting to create an adjacency matrix for counties in AL, SC, and GA and I tried one approach which seemed to work well. I used the following libraries and code to generate the adjacency matrix (Adj_mat).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(spdep)
library(urbnmapr)

counties_sf <- get_urbn_map("counties", sf = TRUE)

counties_south <- filter(counties_sf, state_abbv %in% c("AL", "GA", "SC" ))

south_counties_polylist <- poly2nb(counties_south)

Adj_mat <- nb2mat(south_counties_polylist, style = "B", zero.policy = T)           # Adjacency matrix
```

The total adjacencies for this matrix are `1526` as obtained by
`m1 <- apply(Adj_mat, 2, sum)`.

This was a bit concerning since I have another adjacency matrix for AL, GA, and SC that I have been using for a while now and has `1528` total adjacencies. I don't have the code that was used to create this matrix and I'm a bit unsure if my approach was wrong or the existing adjacency matrix that I have been using is not correct.

Based on the package description, `urbnmapr` library uses shapefiles from the US Census Bureau. I would like to be able to create matrices for different states on my own and would appreciate any pointers to ensure I'm doing it correctly. Thank you!

Comment: Adjacency matrices are very sensitive to conditions like when counties share only a single point, or where four counties meet at a point, or where digitised boundaries are a tiny amount (like centimetres on the ground) different. Can you find the 2 extra adjacencies in the 1528 set and plot the counties? (It might only be one adjacency and its inverse). That might explain it.

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks for the feedback and suggestions! I believe it's one adjacency and its inverse due to symmetry. I will see if I can find which adjacency it's.

Comment: I tried the county polygons from the ```counties()``` function in  ```tigris```  ```r``` package and it worked well. My two adjacency matrices for AL, GA, and SC now agree. Tigris uses TIGER/Lines shapefiles from the US Census.